# ASP.NET MVC Url display problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-profiles, html-encode

I have recently been experimenting with the profile features of ASP.NET. I am having trouble getting a "website" property to display correctly. For example, if the website I enter is:

```
facebook.com/contactalig
```

and I render it using
`<a href="<%: Profile.Website %>"><%: Profile.Website %></a>`
 it gets rendered on screen as

```
http://localhost:51225/users/facebook.com/contactalig
```

Initially, I thought I might just prepend "http://" if it didn't contain one, but I feel there should be a cleaner solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the protocol etc it isn't an absolute uri, so the browser (correctly) treats it as relative to the current URL.

So yes: check for a protocol. Perhaps just StartsWith is enough here, else a regex or maybe Uri.TryCreate (or whatever it is) specifying absolute-only.

Personally I would do this check at the point of data-entry, not at display.